# PHP mysql_query return decoded encoded data

Tags: php, mysql, search

I used htmlspecialchars on column at my database called 'Description'.

I got search page in my website which return results using this mysql_query sentence: 

"SELECT * FROM db.db WHERE NameOfEvent LIKE '%".$q."%'"

I added the following string to the database: "`test&test`".
because I used htmlspecialchars, in the database it will look like this: "`test&amp;test`"

If I type 'a' at the search, test&test will be one of the results... how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't save your values with `htmlspecialchars()`. This should be used for output/display.

If you must, consider doing so in an additional column, i.e. `formatted_description`. This way you can still search on `description`.

Probably not the answer you want. But...

Comment: There should be no "if you must"! Don't store stuff like this HTML encoded in the database.

Comment: @Jame C, complete agree. Just trying to offer something to the OP. *Don't do that* isn't the best answer. :)

Comment: wasn't disagreeing with you, just being less polite!

Comment: I stored the data encoded because I thought its better, if it doesnt matter then I have no reason to store it encoded. I will decode the data and encode it only when I want to display it. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should store the data in your database unencoded and then use htmlspecialchars on it when you get it back, prior to display.

As it stands at the moment, you'd have to jump through hoops to get your search for '%a%' to ignore `&amp;`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the way in which MySQL searchs strings into tables. You can just change the way in which you save the strings in your fields.
Maybe you could try to save the text in the Desfription flield without using htmlspecialchars(). And using it just after the extraction from the db.